# With one click I want to open link in new window and also 2 new tabs in previous window

Tags: html, image, tabs, window

I want to open image link in new window and also 2 new tabs in previous window at a time .
Kindly tell me how i can do this with html/java script code or whatever way ?

Answer (score 1):

just simply you should add javascript event on image link and use this code;

```
<a id="test" href="your address for main window"> <img> </img> </a>
<script type="text/javascript">

   document.getElementById("test").onclick = function(){
      window.open("url to open in new tab",'_blank');
      return true;
   }
</script>
```

important to give a return true (or don't using a return in onclick function).

If you wanna do it in only js you can execute two window functions on onclick:

```
document.getElementById("test").onclick = function(){
   window.open("url to open in new tab",'_blank');
   window.open("url to open in main window",'_blank');
}
```

something like that should work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Technically it depends on the individual settings of the users browser to open URLs in tabs or new windows so whatever you use will be subject to those settings and potentially unreliable.